# Lift-Json Extracting from JSON object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, lift-json

I have this code below:

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
          val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark").setMaster("local[2]")
          val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

          val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))
          val kafkaBrokers = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "HostName:9092")
          val offsetMap = Map(TopicAndPartition("topic_test", 0), 8) 
          val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaBrokers, offsetMap)

var offsetArray = Array[OffsetRange]()
                lines.transform {rdd =>
                        offsetArray = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
                        rdd
                }.map {
                        _.message()
                }.foreachRDD {rdd =>
                     /* NEW CODE */
                }
                ssc.start()
                ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

I have added the new code uder the comment `/* NEW CODE */`. My question is the lines `val` will contain a sequence of RDD's which basically form the kafka sever every 3 seconds. Then I am grabbing the message using the map function.

But I am a little confused on what the `foreachRDD` function does. Does that iterate over all of the `RDD's` which are in the `lines DStream` (which is what I am trying to do)? The thing is the parse function from the `lift-json` library only accepts a string so I need to iterate over all of the rdd's and pass that String value to the parse function which is what I attempted to do. **But nothing is being printed out for some reason.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read data from a specific offset, you're using the wrong overload.

The one you need is this:

```
createDirectStream[K, 
                   V,
                   KD <: Decoder[K], 
                   VD <: Decoder[V], R]
                   (ssc: StreamingContext,
                    kafkaParams: Map[String, String], 
                    fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long], 
                    messageHandler: (MessageAndMetadata[K, V]) ⇒ R): InputDStream[R]
```

You need a `Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]`:

```
val offsetMap = Map(TopicAndPartition("topic_test", 0), 8L)
```

And you need to pass a function which receives a `MessageAndMetadata[K, V]` and returns your desired type, for example:

```
val extractKeyValue: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (String, String) = 
      msgAndMeta => (msgAndMeta.key(), msgAndMeta.message())
```

And use it:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder]
(ssc, kafkaBrokers, offsetMap, extractKeyValue)
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much! Just one question. In this line here: `val extractKeyValue: MessageAndMetadata[String, String] => (String, String) = msgAndMeta => (msgAndMeta.key(), msgAndMeta.message())` What exactly is `msgAndMeta.key(), msgAndMeta.message()` returning like in the tuple? Is it `(TOPIC_NAME, MESSAGE)`?

Comment: @1290 When you're inserting a record to Kafka, you specify a key and a value. So the `key()` is the key, and `message()` is the value. This method creates a `Tuple2` of them.

Comment: Ohh ok I see. Can you please answer my one another question I have regarding the work flow of this streaming job. So essentially my spark streaming context will be streaming data from the kafka brokers I specified in my `kafkaParams` map starting at the `0th` partition and the `8th` offset as specified in my `offsetMap`. So now my question is: Every 3 seconds will it run that code I added to my question under the comment `NEW CODE PLEASE REFER HERE`?

Comment: If you want it to read from the specific offset in each partition, you'll need a key value pair in your `Map` for each partition, meaning `Map(TopicAndPartition("topic_test", 0) -> 8, TopicAndPartition("topic_test", 1) -> 8)`,etc. Other then that, yes, that code will execute every batch interval you define.

Comment: Ahh ok. Got it. That is exactly what I did as you stated by adding the key value pair in my map to read from each partition. Also sorry if I am asking too much, but for that createDirectStream we pass all of these params in the `[]` `String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder` What exactly are those params for? I tried researching online but was not able to find a clear explanation. I feel like I am just copy pasting some code without understanding what it really does.

Comment: @1290 It's ok. The first `String` is the type of the key (`K`). The second value is for the type of the value (`V`). The third is for the decoder of the key, which is used to decode the key you send from Kafka, and the fourth is the decoder for the value. These type parameters help the Scala compiler infer the right types.

Comment: So when you say `These type parameters help the Scala compiler infer the right types.` Are you referring to the return types? So that scala know what the return types will be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116235/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-1290).

Comment: Hey! If you don't mind can I ask you one more quick question regarding this post?

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post above in the `/* NEW CODE */` portion. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @1290 Are you running this in a cluster? If so, foreachRDD will execute on the worker nodes. Look in their stderr via the Spark UI

Comment: Yes this is running on a cluster. But I am having trouble in that `foreachRDD` method with parsing the JSON. Since the rdd variable in that foreachRDD method is an `rdd` but I need the string's in that RDD which is why I do the `map` function with the elem `val`. But I don't think that method is working either

Comment: *"I don't think it's working either"* Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116514/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-1290).

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to do in spark? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254316/create-a-large-rdd-from-rdds-in-dstream