# Create a large RDD from RDD's in DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Does anyone know a way to create a large RDD from a sequence of RDD's in a DStream for a specific batch interval:

For example in the code below:

```
def createLargeRDD() {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))

    val DStream = KafkaUtilHelper.RetrieveDStream(ssc)

    DStream.transform { rdd =>
      /* Form an RDD with all of the RDD's that were put into the 
         DStream variable above for the 3 seconds batch interval */     
      rdd
    }
}
```

So RDD's are being added to that DStream variable every 3 seconds. Is there a way I can aggregate all of those RDD's that are in the DStream for that 3 second time period into one large RDD and save that RDD to HBase or some external source.

Comment: Why would you want to aggregate them all to one `RDD`? That's kind of missing the point of streaming. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Like the DStream contains RDD's of type of String which hold some JSON data and I want to put all of that JSON data in one single RDD and save that RDD to elastic search. But you are right that defeats the purpose of streaming.